# Sort a 2D Points List (first by X and then Y)

Tags: c#, sorting, icomparable, points

I am trying to sort a List of 2D Points first by x co-ordinate and then by y co-ordinate.
I implemented the IComparer interface as follows:

```
class PointComparer : IComparer<Point>
{
    public int Compare(Point x, Point y)
    {
        if (x.Y != y.Y)
        {
            return x.Y - y.Y;
        }
        else
        {
            return x.X - y.X;
        }

    }
}
```

And then call my sorting as follows:

```
pointsList.Sort(new PointComparer());
```

For some reason the list doesn't sort. Surely is something very simple and silly, but stuck on this for quite a while....TIA

Comment: Why are you comparing `IntPoint` with `Point`?

Comment: sorry that was a mistake. corrected.

Comment: Doesn't that sort by Y and then by X? Also, `x` and `y` are terrible names in this context.

Comment: By "doesn't sort", do you mean that the list is in the same order as the one you started with, or just that it doesn't work correctly?

Comment: means doesn't sort at all and original order stays.

Comment: @kobi - doesn't matter if first y then x or vice versa...just need an ordered 2d set.

Comment: Your code *works as posted*, so your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Similar, if not duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493740/sort-points-vertically-then-horizontally

Comment: I **hate** when there are only linq answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work better:

```
class PointComparer : IComparer<Point>
{
  public int Compare(Point first, Point second)
  {
    if (first.X == second.X)
    {
        return first.Y - second.Y;
    }
    else
    {
        return first.X - second.X;
    }

  }
}
```

If the X values are different, it will use the Y value for sorting. This is different from your code, where X values will be used if the Y values are the same.

As others have mentioned, if you can use Linq, you should use the `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` extension methods:

```
pointsList.OrderBy(p => p.X).ThenBy(p => p.y)
```

Comment: Thx. but no luck, the original order stays unchanged.

Comment: this is almost the same as he had, except yours has a typo "first.X == first.X"... that is always true, so the else would never hit

Answer (score 1):

Could you not use OrderBy -> ThenBy?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx

Comment: While this should work, this is not what the OP asked.  He wants to know what he is doing wrong with his approach (i.e. Why is using a Comparer not working)

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
var sorted = pointsList.OrderBy(p => p.X)
                       .ThenBy(p => p.y)
```

Comment: While this should work, this is not what the OP asked.  He wants to know what he is doing wrong with his approach (i.e. Why is using a Comparer not working)